# Looking for free, specific Ip2Location Database

Tags: database, free, geolocation

I am searching for a free db (like an updated XML or CSV file) that relates IP addresses to specific locations. I want more information than just the country. 
I want some sort of region or city reference, even if that ends up to be a number that makes no sense to me.
Doesn't have to be super correct or always up to date either. 
It is just to distinguish between user groups and not to monitor or spy on them.

Comment: I've found the MaxMind was the fastest when making API calls because you actually host the database on your local file system. If you're checking hundreds of IP's at once i'd go with MaxMind. But testing API's speeds is pretty easy as constructing the POST URL's is pretty easy with all of them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many IP to Location databases/services there, but going for free will cost in limited number of API calls, and features (paid one gives comparatively more). Freeness of service and the accuracy of service is inversely proportional to each other. Listed below are some services arranged by accurate (or more feature) to free:

---

### MaxMind

Offers features like: Country Code, Country Name, Region as well as province/state name, city, postal code, latitude, longitude, ISP. Their databases are bigger. You can know more about it at http://www.maxmind.com/app/lookup_city

### Geo I/O

Offers location (City, State, Country), latitudes and longitudes, ISP, Zip Code and Area code. Only the downside is it limits the API calls to 1000 perday. It also have some paid plans. You can get it @ http://www.geoio.com/

### NetIP

It offers city, country, postal code, latitude and longitude. You can directly make a call at `http://www.netip.de/search?query=$ip`. It has obsolete database IMO. Similar is `http://api.hostip.info?ip=x.x.x.x`

---

Each services has their own updside and downside. Its upon you to choose. In my personal view the Geo I/O is better of all.

***Further Reading***

1. [What service exist that geo-locate a person based on IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464142/what-services-exist-that-geo-locates-a-person-based-on-ip)
2. [Geo Location Based on IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464142/what-services-exist-that-geo-locates-a-person-based-on-ip)

Comment: geoio.com now limits to 250 hits/day